# Show vertical tracking line on hover over multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show a vertical line that will appear as and of my charts are hovered over and will disappear when the mouse exits the chart elements. Weirdly, the `mouseleave` and `mouseout` events seem to fire when the mouse is not moving or when it is moving up and down (rather than side-to-side), see the code snippet below. I don't want the line to disappear when the mouse pauses and I want it to track the mouse wherever it goes.

I've tried firing the code on hover, `mouseenter` and `mouseover` but `mousemove` (see below code) is the only event that continuously fires as the position of the cursor changes.

```js
//$(document).ready(function() {
 function showVerticalLine(e) {
  var topBarHeight = 56;
    var bottomHeight = 100;
  var posX = $(this).offset().left;
  var x = e.pageX;
  var y = $(window).innerHeight();
    
    //Change line so that it appears at the position of the cursor
  $('.verticalTrackerLine').css({
   'opacity': '1',
   'left': x,
   'top': topBarHeight,
   'height': y - topBarHeight - bottomHeight + "px",
   'transition': 'left 0.1s'
  });
    
    //Update string to show when the charts are being hovered over
  $("#testSTRING").html('you are moving/hovering');
 };
 
 function hideVerticalLine(){
    //Hide the line
  $('.verticalTrackerLine').css({
   'opacity': '0'
  });
    
    //Update string to show when the charts are being hovered over
  $("#testSTRING").html('you have left');
 }
  
  $("#chart1").add("#chart2").mousemove(showVerticalLine);
  $("#chart1").add("#chart2").mouseout(hideVerticalLine);
//})
```

```css
.chart {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}

.verticalTrackerLine {
  border-left: 2px dashed RGB(68,74,79);
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<SPAN id="testSTRING"></SPAN>
<SPAN class="verticalTrackerLine"></SPAN>

<DIV id="chart1" class="chart">Chart 1</DIV>
<DIV id="chart2" class="chart">Chart 2</DIV>



</head>
```

Any help/suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: I think I have just had an idea - I think that when the line appears, the JQuery interprets that I am no longer over the element because the line is in the way. Is there a solution to this? An easy solution might be to offset the line by a pixel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is right, when you hover over the actual line that interferes with hovering over the buttons.  So, just adding `pointer-events: none;` to the `.verticalTrackerLine` selector will fix this so that the mouse has no interaction with the line at all.

I also did some minor JS cleanup on your code, nothing too major. The CSS rule `transition: left 0.1s` doesn't need to be re-applied every time the mouse moves, so that has now been set in the CSS instead.

```js
$(function() {
    var topBarHeight = 56;
    var bottomHeight = 100;
    var $line = $('.verticalTrackerLine');
    var $charts = $("#chart1, #chart2");
    var $test = $("#testSTRING");

    function showVerticalLine(e) {
      var posX = $(this).offset().left;
      var x = e.pageX;
      var y = $(window).innerHeight();

      //Change line so that it appears at the position of the cursor
      $line.css({
        'opacity': 1,
        'left': x,
        'top': topBarHeight,
        'height': y - topBarHeight - bottomHeight + "px"
      });

      //Update string to show when the charts are being hovered over
      $test.html('you are moving/hovering');
    };

    function hideVerticalLine() {
      //Hide the line
      $line.css('opacity', 0);

      //Update string to show when the charts are being hovered over
      $test.html('you have left');
    }

    $charts
      .mousemove(showVerticalLine)
      .mouseout(hideVerticalLine);
});
```

```css
.chart {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}

.verticalTrackerLine {
  border-left: 2px dashed RGB(68, 74, 79);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: left 0.1s;/* <------ this was moved from JS */
  pointer-events: none; /* <------ this was added */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<output id="testSTRING">nothing has happened yet...</output>
<span class="verticalTrackerLine"></span>

<div id="chart1" class="chart">Chart 1</div>
<div id="chart2" class="chart">Chart 2</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for the extra information on triggering transition too frequently. It is working really well now.

Comment: Glad to help!  One other thing I noticed but wasn't sure about what your final use case is though.  The `top` value is just a static number and it's also set every time the mouse moves.  If this number will never actually need to be calculated from anything, this could also be moved to the CSS.

Comment: Or.. perhaps a better way to get the top position would be to select the top bar element and measure it's height like `$('#top-bar').height()` - you'd only need to measure this once, outside of the mouse events

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it further:

- move the *tracking line* into an `:after` *pseudo element* inside each `chart` element and *position* it *absolutely* within the `chart`
- position it 10px more to the top and bottom using:

  ```
  top: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  ```
- set `opacity: 0` to the *tracking line* and on `:hover` set it to one - now you'll have the line on hover - see demo below:

```css
.chart {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.chart:after {
  content: '';
  border-left: 2px dashed rgb(68, 74, 79);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
}

.chart:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart1" class="chart">Chart 1</div>
<div id="chart2" class="chart">Chart 2</div>
```

Now comes the *javascript part* - we can modify the `left` property to show the line moving with the mouse:

- first add a *CSS variable* (say `--left`) that can be adjusted from JS
- now in a `mousemove` listener you can use `e.pageX - this.offsetLeft` to get the *relative position* (`left` value) of the mouse inside the box.
- update the `--left` CSS variable using `document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--left', ...`
- Note that I've made a *maximum* value for the `left` value to be on the safe side to `this.offsetWidth - 2`.

See demo below:

```js
$(".chart").mousemove(function (e) {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--left', Math.min(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, this.offsetWidth - 2) + 'px');
});
```

```css
:root {
  --left: 0;
}

.chart {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.chart:after {
  content: '';
  border-left: 2px dashed rgb(68, 74, 79);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: var(--left);
}

.chart:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart1" class="chart">Chart 1</div>
<div id="chart2" class="chart">Chart 2</div>
```

Comment: Now that's cool, I've not seen CSS variables used in that way before!

Comment: This is great but unfortunately I can't edit the css for the charts in the program I am using. There is lots of useful stuff for me in the comment though so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to `.verticalTrackerLine`

```js
//$(document).ready(function() {
 function showVerticalLine(e) {
  var topBarHeight = 56;
    var bottomHeight = 100;
  var posX = $(this).offset().left;
  var x = e.pageX;
  var y = $(window).innerHeight();
    
    //Change line so that it appears at the position of the cursor
  $('.verticalTrackerLine').css({
   'opacity': '1',
   'left': x,
   'top': topBarHeight,
   'height': y - topBarHeight - bottomHeight + "px",
   'transition': 'left 0.1s'
  });
    
    //Update string to show when the charts are being hovered over
  $("#testSTRING").html('you are moving/hovering');
 };
 
 function hideVerticalLine(){
    //Hide the line
  $('.verticalTrackerLine').css({
   'opacity': '0'
  });
    
    //Update string to show when the charts are being hovered over
  $("#testSTRING").html('you have left');
 }
  
  $("#chart1").add("#chart2").mousemove(showVerticalLine);
  $("#chart1").add("#chart2").mouseout(hideVerticalLine);
//})
```

```css
.chart {
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}

.verticalTrackerLine {
  border-left: 2px dashed RGB(68,74,79);
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   opacity: 0;
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<SPAN id="testSTRING"></SPAN>
<SPAN class="verticalTrackerLine"></SPAN>

<DIV id="chart1" class="chart">Chart 1</DIV>
<DIV id="chart2" class="chart">Chart 2</DIV>



</head>
```